# How to perofrm a simple GARCH simulation example?

Tags: stochastic-processes, garch, models

How is it possible to simulate one million of tick data for, say EUR-USD price, using a [GARCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity#GARCH) model?

For example, how do I simulate $X_i$ for $i = 1 \dots 1000000$, with

- $\text{mean}(X)=X_0 \approx 1.1042$
- $\text{stddev}(X) \approx 0.10$

*Even if it's possible with ready to use libraries, I'd like to be able to write it from scratch (Python or R).*

Comment: What have you tried so far? I mean there are obvious parameters missing from your input here, do you realized that? Maybe you should have a look at the model definition again and include it in your question. It would help you start for sure.

Comment: @SRKX In fact I don't really understand the [notations here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity#GARCH). What is $x'_t$ ? $\Psi_t$ ? The wikipedia page in its current state is rather un-explicit. (Or maybe it is obvious when you *already* know GARCH, but *a priori* it's pretty difficult to learn with this page)

Comment: Then I suggest you go on [stats.se] to understand what GARCH is from a purely mathematical point of view, and then you can ask a question specific about the financial simulation aspect of it in here.